# Create a button to delete a specific record in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to create a button to delete badges. Except that I do not want to delete the badge, but to delete the subscription to a badge if i can say.

```
<% @subscribeds.each do |badge| %>
<span class="badge badge-secondary"> 
<%= link_to 'Delete', controller: 'listdedistribution',id: Listdedistribution.find_by(group_id: badge.id, user_id: current_user.id, origine: "Self-registered").id, action: :destroy, method: :delete, :class => "fas fa-trash-alt fa-lg" %> 
<%= badge.name %>
</span>
<% end %>
```

I get the following error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (No route matches {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"listdedistribution", :id=>18458, :locale=>:en, :method=>:delete}):
```

Does anybody know how to target a specific records and delete it please?
Thank you

Comment: check rails routes
Do you have routes defined like,

 DELETE    /listdedistribution/:id(.:format)     listdedistribution#destroy

Comment: No i do not, have that one. How can i exactly add that one pls? I only have the resources one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check your routes

```
resources :listdedistribution # in routes

DELETE   /listdedistribution/:id(.:format)    listdedistribution#destroy
```

Comment: Hey, i have the following :  DELETE /listdedistributions/:id(.format)(.:format) 
listdedistributions#destroy.

Comment: Hey, i still have the following : ActionView::Template::Error (No route matches {:action=>"destroy", :class=>"fas fa-trash-alt fa-lg", :controller=>"listdedistribution", :id=>18458, :locale=>:en, :method=>:delete}) despite using resources.

Comment: Try in your rails console.helper.link_to "delete", "listdedistribution", :method => 'delete', :id=>4545

Comment: 2.5.3 :001 > console.helper.link_to "delete", "listdedistribution", :method => 'delete', :id=> 18469
Traceback (most recent call last):
        1: from (irb):1
NoMethodError (undefined method `helper' for nil:NilClass)

Comment: Your html should be like this <a data-confirm="Are you sure?" rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/listdedistribution/18469">Delete</a>